# Image resizing on mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

I have implemented a slider (http://pgwjs.com/pgwslider/) for a client but his requirements are that if a user clicks the image on the current slide, then that image should re-size automatically to a bigger size and on second click it should get minimized to original size!

> **How can I implement this function??**

Comment: Probably best to put a click function on the main image to change class of the container and change your css accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use toggleClass function of jquery to apply class on first click and remove class on another click. In the first click apply active and set size on this active class in css.

```
$('slider img').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("test");
});
```

CSS

```
.test {
height:100px;
width:200px;
}
```

You can try like this please update classes name

Comment: can u provide a code fragment to implement this function if possible?

Comment: thanks for the snippet...but s there any slider already having this type of function?

Comment: No It's custom function you need to use this code in your JS file

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pgwSlider').toggleClass('.larger');
});
```

...where '.larger' is a CSS class that makes the slider larger perhaps?

Or if you wanted to make just the image bigger rather than the whole slider, you could use jQuery to make the image appear and disappear again, by changing its CSS Visibility property.

Comment: I dont want to make the whole slider larger on mouse click, but just the current image in the slider..

Answer (score -1):

The HTML will be like this
< img src="/resources/pen.png" id="pen" class="small"/>

the css will be like this

```
img.small {
    width: 100px;
}

img.large {
    width: 500px;
}
```

The jQuery code will be like this

```
$("img#pen").click(function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass("large");
    $(this).toggleClass("small");
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ranjitswain297/gTJ9z/2/)

Comment: You don't need to define different different classes in case of toggle class, It will add class and remove on click

Comment: correct. if i want to apply a default css for the image and assume that is small, then i have to remove that small css class and apply the large css class. in that case i think it is applicable.
I don't want to give !important in the style sheet rule. for that reason i have to remove previous style sheet rule and i have to give new style sheet rule. for that reason the small css class is removed and large is applied.
because in the small css width is 100px and in large the width is 500px. the browser will always take greater amount (500px) if you apply two class.

Comment: no matter what is the sequence of class you apply. either "small large" or "large small".